# Insere linhas em branco ao inserir foreach

Tags: php, mysql

Estou a inserir na mesma coluna todos os dados do meu formulário, que contém checkboxes e inputs type="number":

```
$calendar .= "<td bgcolor='#F5F5F5' align='center' data-semana=''><center><font size='2px'/> 
    <input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][dia]' value='$year-$month-$day' $marcado_data $disabled> $year-$month-$day <br /> 
    <input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][OpcaoA]' value='Peq_Almoço' $marcado_pequeno $disabled> Peq. Almoço <input $disabled type='number' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][Qtd]' style='width:65px; height: 22px' /> <br /> 
    <input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][opcaoB]' value='Almoço' $marcado_almoco $disabled> Almoço <input $disabled type='number' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][Qtd1]' style='width:65px; height: 22px' /> <br /> 
    <input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][opcaoC]' value='Almoço_(Dieta)' $marcado_dieta $disabled> Almoço (Dieta) <input $disabled type='number' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][Qtd2]' style='width:65px; height: 22px' /> <br /> 
    <input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][opcaoD]' value='Lanche' $marcado_lanche $disabled> Lanche <input $disabled type='number' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][Qtd3]' style='width:65px; height: 22px' /><br /> 
    <input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][opcaoE]' value='Jantar' $marcado_jantar $disabled> Jantar <input $disabled type='number' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][Qtd4]' style='width:65px; height: 22px' /> <br /> 
    <input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][opcaoF]' value='Jantar_(Dieta)' $marcado_jantardie $disabled> Jantar (Dieta) <input $disabled type='number' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][Qtd5]' style='width:65px; height: 22px' /> </font></center></td>";
}
```

Estou a inserir na tabela desta forma:

```
if(!empty($_POST['arrachar'])){
    // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox. 
    foreach($_POST['arrachar'] as $selected){ 
        $string = implode(',', $selected);
        $sql="INSERT INTO marcacao (arrachar) VALUES('$string')";
        $r = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);      
    }
}
```

Aqui mostro como está a inserir os dados:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas só devia inserir a primeira linha e devia parar, porque foi o único dia em que marquei refeições, mas insere os dias restantes até ao final do mês mesmo estando vazios.
Como posso resolver o problema?

Comment: Quando você diz que utiliza o mesmo `insert`, você inclui a coluna para os `values` dos inputs "number" correto?

Comment: Não, estou a tentar inserir os dados todos na mesma coluna, na coluna arrachar onde insiro as checkboxes

Comment: Alterei o name dos 'inputs type="number" e utilizo exatamente igual o insert que postei acima, mas insere muitas linhas vazias como mostro na pergunta.

Comment: se voce está concatenando todas as variaveis $selected dentro da $string, vc precisa fazer o insert só depois q ele sai do for...

Comment: Vejo que o código `if(!empty($_POST['arrachar'])){` deveria estar dentro do `foreach` e não antes dele, aí sim vc verificará se cada controle está vazio ou não. Da forma que está, só o primeiro é verificado.

Comment: Mas mesmo assim insere as outras linhas, insere desta forma:`1 2018-04-21,Peq_Almoço,10,Almoço,10,,Lanche,10,,
2 ,,,,,
3 ,,,,,
4 ,,,,,
5 ,,,,,
6 ,,,,,
7 ,,,,,
8 ,,,,,
9 ,,,,,
10 ,,,,,`, só devia inserir a primeira linha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode verificar se a variável `$string` possui uma data, aí só irá inserir os dados que possuírem a data no formato `yyyy/MM/dd`, como demonstra a sua pergunta.

Coloque a linha que faz o INSERT dentro de um `if` com `preg_match` usando a regex `/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/`:

```
if(preg_match('/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/', $string)){
    $sql="INSERT INTO marcacao (arrachar) VALUES('$string')";
}
```

Essa regex irá verificar se na `$string` possui o padrão ***4 dígitos + hífen + 2 dígitos + hífen + 2 dígitos***.